# clip raster with polygon in postgis

Tags: postgis, raster, clip

I am newbie in postgis.

I have a raster landsat images in table "ras" and a polygon shapefile image in table "shp".

Now I want to clip raster with polygon using postgis, but I have a problem

- The raster and polygon have the same `SRID(wgs84)`, but when using `st_intersects()`, the result table are all `FALSE`

Can anybody explain that?

Comment: They don't intersect? It is impossible to say without seeing the data in some way.

Comment: 1) It's not because they have the same SRID that they actually intersect. 2) Do they have the "right" SRID?

Comment: I opened both file metadata, it said datatum is WGS84
and the command I imported 2 file also use "-s" are 4326

Comment: I also try to view data in Qgis and 2 layers are overlap